# Tensorboard not displaying scalars correctly

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am new to Tensorflow, and I have been debugging for this problem for days, but I still couldn't find any solutions to it.

When I print out the loss and reward, it reflects the actual numbers:

```
total step: 79800.00 reward: 6.00, loss: 0.0107212793
....
total step: 98600.00 reward: 5.00, loss: 0.0002098639
total step: 98700.00 reward: 6.00, loss: 0.0061239433
```

However, when I plot them on the Tensorboard, there are three problems:

1. There is a Z-shape loss. How can there be multiple loss values at the same time step?
2. The loss get flatten out and seems to be a constant after certain steps.
3. The average_reward and episode_reward are always zero on Tensorboard.

This is the screenshot of my Tensorboard:

screenshot :

[image]

Why do these three problems occur and how can I fix it?

Here is the code, a function I call at the end of every training step:

```
def make_summary(self):
    self.env.render()

    if self.episode == 1:
        self.writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./train")
    if self.step > self.start_learning and self.step % self.train_freq == 0:
        if not self.added_scalars:
            self.writer.add_graph(self.sess.graph)
            self.episode_reward_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=None,name='episode_reward_ph')
            self.average_reward_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=None,name='average_reward_ph')
            tf.summary.scalar('episode_reward', self.episode_reward_ph)
            tf.summary.scalar('average_reward', self.average_reward_ph)
            tf.summary.scalar('loss', self.l)
            self.summ = tf.summary.merge_all()
            self.added_scalars = True
        else:
            with self.sess.as_default():
                self.merged_summary = self.sess.run(self.summ, feed_dict = {self.episode_reward_ph: self.final_episode_reward,
                                                                            self.average_reward_ph: self.average_reward})
                self.writer.add_summary(self.merged_summary, self.step)
                self.writer.flush()
```

Comment: Does it show same behavior if you change the horizontal axis to RELATIVE or WALL  on tensorboard?

Comment: The Z-shape now becomes a slope sliding towards another side, i.e., the first problem disappeared. But the second and third problems are still there. What could have gone wrong?